# Chrome can't see images that require username/password

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming

So this is a weird problem, I am attempting to embed a video stream from a D-Link DCS-930L into a web page. My embed looks like this:

`<img alt="" src="http://guest:password@192.0.0.10/video.cgi">`

The problem is that Chrome displays a broken link image when I load the page, while Firefox and IE load it perfectly the first time.

But the really strange part is that if I right click on the broken image > Open link in new tab the stream loads, and then if I close the tab and refresh the page with the embed it loads there too! So it's definitely something to do with the username/password requirement.

I have also tried creating a user without a password but I see the same issue. There is no setting to disable this requirement in the 930L's control panel that I can find.

Does anyone know how to fix this? If not, is there a way to use PHP to execute a login automatically for the above kind of URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [appears to be intentional](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123150) behavior on Chrome's part since v19. Bummer.